# What's the connection & difference between mockito & powermock & powermockito?

Tags: mockito

I studied mockito test framework, and learned about powermock, but I suddenly found a framework called powermockito, I can't understand anymore.

Can anyone tell me the difference between these three test utils?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The Mockito is the market standard mocking framework that tastes good. It provides many functionalities like mocking, stubbing, verifying the methods calls, etc. In previous versions, it did not provide the possibility to mock private or static methods (here is the explanation why: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mockito-And-Private-Methods). Than The really helpful was the
2. Powermock uses a custom classloader and bytecode manipulation to enable mocking of static methods, constructors, final classes and methods, private methods, removal of static initializers, and more. But when You have to use the Powermock probably your application design is poor
3. I've never used the PowerMockito but it is a PowerMock's extension API to support Mockito. It provides capabilities to work with the Java Reflection API in a simple way to overcome the problems of Mockito, such as the lack of ability to mock final, static or private methods.

But nowadays (starting from mockito 3.4) there is a possibility to mock the static methods - then the usage of PowerMock can be limited. Here is a nice blog post about it https://tech.cognifide.com/blog/2020/mocking-static-methods-made-possible-in-mockito-3.4.0/

Comment: Thx a lot , this blog really helpful!